# selecting out even number only once without repeating the same number in python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, append

`list1 = [2,4,6,8,3,4,2,]`
From the above list I need to obtain the  following result
`[2,4,6,8]`

Here is the way that how I tried. But it resulted an error without giving the expected result.

```py
list1 = [2,4,6,8,3,4,2,]
x=[]
for num in list1:
    if (num % 2 == 0) and (num not in list1):
        x.append(num)
        print(x)
```

so I need your help to selecting out even numbers only once without repeating the same number
Thanks in Advance...!

Comment: `(num not in list1)` is always `False` hence `and` conjunction returns always `False` and the list will never be updated. That condition should be replaced with `... (num not in x):`. See answer of Sumit S Chawla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made minor modification to your code, and simply apply `set()` to get only the unique values, and `list()` to convert it to a list, and `sorted()` to get the values in ascending order

```
list1 = [2,4,6,8,3,4,2,1]
x=[]
for num in list1:
    if (num % 2 == 0):
        x.append(num)
print(sorted(list(set(x))))
```

Output

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Edit: If you need the results to appear in the same order as the original list, you will need to specify the second condition `(num not in x)`, and no need to use `set()` anymore

```
list1 = [4,2,8,3,6,5]
x=[]
for num in list1:
    if (num % 2 == 0) and (num not in x):
        x.append(num)

print(sorted(list(set(x))))
print(list(set(x)))
print(set(x))
print(x)    #this is the output you're looking for
```

Output

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
[8, 2, 4, 6]
{8, 2, 4, 6}
[4, 2, 8, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you Raven. This gave me the expected answer for this question. but  if the given list did not in any order such as ascending or descending we can not use the sort method isn't it ? so is there any other way to obtain the result ? 
eg: list1= [4,2,8,3,6,5]     and to obtain result [4,2,8,6]
if you have a free time please help me.. thanks again..

Comment: @Hesin Alwis `set` doesn't respect the insertion order hence any `set`-based answer will have such side-effects also if using `sort`. Check out other answers as well!

Comment: hi @HesinAlwis, the method `sorted()` can be omitted if you do not need to order the list. Do you need the results to be in a certain order?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the number in `x` as [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) data type, which prevent duplication, instead of list

```
list1 = [2,4,6,8,3,4,2]
x=set()
for num in list1:
    if (num % 2 == 0):
      x.add(num)

print(list(x))
```

Alternatively, if you want to respect the order of the input you can have 1 set and 1 list. The set (`x_set`) is used for efficient check to see if a number is already in the list and the list (`x_output`) is used for storing the output

```
list1 = [2,4,6,8,3,4,2]
x_set=set()
x_output = []
for num in list1:
    if (num % 2 == 0) and (num not in x_set):
      x_set.add(num)
      x_output.append(num)

print(x_output)
```

Comment: now the `print` should be deindent

Comment: `set` will not respect the insertion order

Comment: I don't think OP question requires correct sorted order

Comment: @tax Thank you for the reply. I am expecting this result [2,4,6,8] . but your code gave following result 
{2}
{2, 4}
{2, 4, 6}
{8, 2, 4, 6}
{8, 2, 4, 6}
{8, 2, 4, 6}

Comment: in that case why not mention in the answer?

Comment: @HesinAlwis Oh I see, if you only need to print the `x` once then you can bring it outside of the `for` loop and convert it to the `list` type

Comment: thanks @taxevader your second answer gave the expected result

Answer (score 1):

With list comprehension, one line is enough. First iterate over the list and test for even. Then convert in set to eliminate duplicates. After return to list:

```
list({x for x in list1 if x % 2 <= 0})
```

Output: [8, 2, 4, 6]

After comments and clarifies, another code is enough:

```
[list1[x] for x in [0] if list1[x] % 2 <= 0] + [list1[i] for i in range(len(list1)) if list1[i] % 2 <= 0 and list1[i] not in list1[0: i - 1]]
```

Output: [2, 4, 6, 8]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go ahead with the same logic, you can update the `if` condition:

```
list1 = [2,4,6,8,3,4,2,]
x=[]
for num in list1:
    if (num % 2 == 0) and (num not in x):
        x.append(num)
        print(x)
```

Other Solution could be using `list comprehension` and `set`:

```
list1 = [2,4,6,8,3,4,2,]
l_set = set(list1)
nums = [val for val in l_set if val%2 == 0]
print(nums)
```